# Select Image of horizontal recyclerview through DPAD

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing `Android TV` app. In my app there is a requirement to display different type of category vertically. Each category has some dynamic no of data that needs to display horizontally. For full fill this requirement I used Horizontally `RecyclerView` to display category data horizontaly under `ListView` that display category vertically. It is working on Touch scroll but for TV we need `DPAD` to select and perform on category Item.  When we scroll up and down through `DPAD` control vertically its select category row but in row we want to scroll and select  category data one by one horizontally but it is not working.
[Here is screen that I want to make and control with DPAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdN75.png).
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Providing DPAD navigation on adapter patterns is complex. Why can't you use dedicated libraries for TV apps. Try Android Leanback library's RowsFragment. It will fulfill your requirement.

RowsFragment Documentation-https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/RowsFragment.html

Example- It will give clear idea about Rows Fragment.

http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-2-85.html

I hope it will help you.